# How to resume the hibernation on Windows in different hardware or in VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, hibernate

I have a disk that I have hibernated using totally different hardware to the current one and I would like to recover the hibernation because I had jobs that I need now.

I've thought about using Disk2vhd to try to resume inside VirtualBox but I'm not sure it works.

My operating system is Windows 7. How I can do this?

Comment: Other than using identical hardware I can't conceive of this working. And I mean identical. Otherwise I would expect a crash during the resume.

Comment: Hibernations works like you pause a working machine, resume only works on original hardware only. If you change something in the (original hardware's) bios, it's enough to break resume posibilities. At the hibernation lot of hardware specific things saved: loaded drivers, memory mapping, opened file pointers, etc) which needs the original environment to continue.

Comment: Try using Disk2vhd, then configure your VM to have **identical** hardware as your real machine.